# Unable To Implement Digest Auth In Android Using bare-bones-digest library

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, digest-authentication

I am trying to implement the **Digest auth** in android. I read many posts and they say **HttpUrlConnection** class does not support the Digest auth. However, I have implemented it using [bare-bones-digest](https://github.com/al-broco/bare-bones-digest) library. Now it is working fine but the API call became very slow. It is taking double time to load the data as compared to it was taking with basic auth. Using base-bones-digest they say to avoid sending each request twice, in subsequent requests the client can reuse the challenge. Only the first request will have to be sent twice. But no implementation is given for that.

```
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        try {
            if(mAuthorizationString != null && !mAuthorizationString.equals("")){
                URL url = new URL(apiEndpoint);
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                DigestAuthentication auth = DigestAuthentication.fromResponse(httpURLConnection);
                // ...with correct credentials
                auth.username("username").password("password");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty(DigestChallengeResponse.HTTP_HEADER_AUTHORIZATION,
                        mAuthorizationString);
            }
            else{
                URL url = new URL(apiEndpoint);
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Step 2. Make the request and check to see if the response contains an authorization challenge
                if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                    // Step 3. Create an authentication object from the challenge...
                    DigestAuthentication auth = DigestAuthentication.fromResponse(httpURLConnection);
                    // ...with correct credentials
                    auth.username("username").password("password");

                    // Step 4 (Optional). Check if the challenge was a digest challenge of a supported type
                    if (!auth.canRespond()) {
                        // No digest challenge or a challenge of an unsupported type - do something else or fail
                        return httpURLConnection;
                    }

                    // Step 5. Create a new connection, identical to the original one...
                    httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    mAuthorizationString = auth.getAuthorizationForRequest(requestMethod, httpURLConnection.getURL().getPath());

                    // ...and set the Authorization header on the request, with the challenge response
                    httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty(DigestChallengeResponse.HTTP_HEADER_AUTHORIZATION,
                            mAuthorizationString);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it Myself by updating the code as follows.

```
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(apiEndpoint);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if(sAuthorizationString != null && !sAuthorizationString.equals("")){
                httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty(DigestChallengeResponse.HTTP_HEADER_AUTHORIZATION,
                        sAuthorizationString);
            }
            else{

                // Step 2. Make the request and check to see if the response contains an authorization challenge
                if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                    // Step 3. Create an authentication object from the challenge...
                    DigestAuthentication auth = DigestAuthentication.fromResponse(httpURLConnection);
                    // ...with correct credentials
                    auth.username("username").password("password");

                    // Step 4 (Optional). Check if the challenge was a digest challenge of a supported type
                    if (!auth.canRespond()) {
                        // No digest challenge or a challenge of an unsupported type - do something else or fail
                        return httpURLConnection;
                    }

                    // Step 5. Create a new connection, identical to the original one...
                    httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    sAuthorizationString = auth.getAuthorizationForRequest(requestMethod, httpURLConnection.getURL().getPath());

                    // ...and set the Authorization header on the request, with the challenge response
                    httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty(DigestChallengeResponse.HTTP_HEADER_AUTHORIZATION,
                            sAuthorizationString);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```